# Boost function "boost::property_tree::ini_parser::read_ini" causing "EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)"

Tags: c++, boost, exc-bad-access, boost-propertytree

I have a simple source like this that build and executes correctly under Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2015 but throws "EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)" under OsX 10.11.3 with Xcode 7.2.1:

```
#include <boost/property_tree/ini_parser.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{    
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        std::cerr << "Usage: program rootPath iniFileName" << std::endl ;
        return 1;
    }        

    string mainPath(argv[1]) ;
    string iniFileName(argv[2])  ;

    boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
    try
    {
        boost::property_tree::ini_parser::read_ini(mainPath + iniFileName, pt);
    }
    catch(const boost::property_tree::ptree_error &e)
    {
        cout << e.what() << endl;
    }

     return 0;
}
```

This is the stack trace:

```
Thread 1Queue : com.apple.main-thread (serial) #0 0x00000001000a10c0 in std::1::basic_streambuf<char, std::1::char_traits<char> >::pubimbue(std::1::locale const&) [inlined] at /Applications/Xcode?.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/streambuf:227 #1 0x00000001000a10c0 in std::1::basic_ios<char, std::1::char_traits<char> >::imbue(std::1::locale const&) [inlined] at /Applications/Xcode?.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/ios:717 #2 0x00000001000a100b in void boost::property_tree::ini_parser::read_ini<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::1::allocator<char> >, std::1::basic_string<char, std::1::char_traits<char>, std::1::allocator<char> >, std::1::less<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::1::allocator<char> > > > >(std::1::basic_string<char, std::1::char_traits<char>, std::1::allocator<char> > const&, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::1::allocator<char> >, std::1::basic_string<char, std::1::char_traits<char>, std::1::allocator<char> >, std::1::less<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::1::allocator<char> > > >&, std::1::locale const&) at /Users/andreagiovacchini/Documents/Sviluppo/boost_1_60_0/boost/property_tree/ini_parser.hpp:167 #3 0x0000000100124a36 in main at /Users/andreagiovacchini/Documents/Sviluppo/Test/Test/main.cpp:21 #4 0x00007fff857245ad in start ()
```

Problem comes from "stream.imbue(loc);" line in ini_parser.php from this function:

```
template<class Ptree>
    void read_ini(const std::string &filename, 
                  Ptree &pt,
                  const std::locale &loc = std::locale())
    {
        std::basic_ifstream<typename Ptree::key_type::value_type>
            stream(filename.c_str());
        if (!stream)
            BOOST_PROPERTY_TREE_THROW(ini_parser_error(
                "cannot open file", filename, 0));
        stream.imbue(loc);
        try {
            read_ini(stream, pt);
        }
        catch (ini_parser_error &e) {
            BOOST_PROPERTY_TREE_THROW(ini_parser_error(
                e.message(), filename, e.line()));
        }
    }
```

Since I can't see how my code can generate this kind of problem I think it is a Boost bug.

I've tryed filing a bug on Boost (https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/11963) but looks like the property_tree bugs are not taken care a lot

Comment: The Boost code also looks fine; try passing `std::locale()` as the third parameter to `read_ini`, from your code. Possibly there are multiple versions of the standard library causing incompatibilities.

Comment: _"but looks like the property_tree bugs are not taken care a lot"_ It doesn't help to call this a Boost bug if you don't actually know what causes it. ISTR locales being practically broken on OSX. You might be able to find something about that online

Comment: @CollinDauphinee: I've tried adding std::locale() but still EXC_BAD_ACCESS, thanks anyway.

Comment: Do you also get a bad access if you do `std::ifstream f(mainPath + iniFileName); f.imbue(std::locale());` ?

Comment: @CollinDauphinee: no, that works

Comment: As a work around, try creating the `ifstream` and passing it to `read_ini` instead of the file name.

Comment: I just ran into something similar with ptree json config trees.

cfg.get<double>() would fail, but cfg.get<std::string> would not. @CollinDauphinee 's answer solved it for me.